# Gravity Forms validate arrival and departure

Tags: validation, plugin-gravity-forms

I am working recently with GF and encounter the first problem: I have two datepicker; one is "arrival" and one is "departure".

Now - of course - the "departure" can't be before "arrival". I've found this script on [Git](https://goo.gl/8qNbki), but I can't get it to work.

Any idea, another workaround to manage this - a fix?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Datepicker Date fields, I've written a plugin that makes this a lot easier and more intuitive for the user by enforcing this limit in the datepicker itself when they're actually selecting the dates. It's called GP Limit Dates:

http://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gp-limit-dates/

Comment: I will end by that - had found it already ;) But the "being proud and get thinks done alone" hold me up to get your plugin. Thank you.

Comment: Haha, I understand. Hopefully you'll let me save you a little time on this one. ;)